# Breadcrumbs customization without use of any module

Tags: breadcrumbs

I have following code in my theme.inc file to generate breadcrumbs from menu url trail. It is working perfectly except for a particular content type nodes. For content type CT1 I am using url alias as home/page1/page2/[node:title]. But that is not reflecting on the CT1 content breadcrumb trail at all. Please advise what I am doing wrong:

```
function mytheme_breadcrumbs($variables)
{
    $breadcrumbs = $variables['breadcrumbs'];
    $crumbs = null;
    if (!empty($breadcrumbs)) {
        $array_size = count($breadcrumbs);
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $array_size) {
            $crumbs .= '<li>' . $breadcrumbs[$i] . '</li>';
            $i++;
        }
        $crumbs .= '<li class="active">' . menu_get_item()['title'] . '</li>';
        return $crumbs;
    } else {
        return '<li class="active">home</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. What is this hook your are using? I couldn't find theme_breadcrumbs on the official documentation. And how is your theme.inc included in your system?